# How to make a HTTP Basic Authentication post request where password is generated by TOTP in node js

Tags: node.js, json, https, hmac, totp

I have successfully completed the other parts of the challenge and am stuck on submitting the request.
please can anyone help me in making a POST request so that i can send in my solution. it's been a real struggle trust me.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
The submission has to follow these rules:

> **Build your solution request**
>
> First, construct a JSON string like below:
>
> {
>
> ```
> "github_url": "https://github.com/YOUR_ACCOUNT/GITHUB_REPOSITORY",
>
> "contact_email": "YOUR_EMAIL"
> ```
>
> }
>
> Fill in your email address for `YOUR_EMAIL`, and the private Github
> repository with your solution in `YOUR_ACCOUNT/GITHUB_REPOSITORY`.
> Then, make an HTTP POST request to the following URL with the JSON
> string as the body part.
>
> ```
> CHALLENGE_URL
> ```
>
> **Content type**
>
> The Content-Type: of the request must be `application/json`.
>
> **Authorization**
>
> The URL is protected by HTTP Basic Authentication, which is explained
> on Chapter 2 of RFC2617, so you have to provide an Authorization:
> header field in your POST request.
>
> - For the userid of HTTP Basic Authentication, use the same email address you put in the JSON string.
> - For the password , provide a 10-digit time-based one time password conforming to RFC6238 TOTP.
>
> **Authorization password**
>
> For generating the TOTP password, you will need to use the following
> setup:
>
> - You have to generate a correct TOTP password according to RFC6238
> - TOTP's `Time Step X` is 30 seconds. `T0` is 0.
> - Use `HMAC-SHA-512` for the hash function, instead of the default `HMAC-SHA-1`.
> - Token shared secret is the userid followed by ASCII string value `"APICHALLENGE"` (not including double quotations).
>
> **Shared secret examples**
>
> For example, if the userid is `"email@example.com"`, the token shared
> secret is `"email@example.comAPICHALLENGE"` (without quotes).
>
> If your POST request succeeds, the server returns HTTP status code 200
> .